# Rails: Render collection: Getting current variable inside partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, collections, rendering

I have a collection with named variable:

```
= render partial: 'universal_partial', collection: districts, as: :district
```

Inside partial I want to get current variable:

```
<li><a><%= current_variable %></a></li>
```

But I have universal partial, it can gets collection from diffirent places:

```
= render partial: 'universal_partial', collection: subways, as: :subway
```

I think, that it would be as:

```
<li><a><%= local_assigns[as] %></a></li>
```

How can I get name of current variable (value of key `:as`) inside partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the 'as' parameter you set the name of your variable. Use the same variable name for all collections:

```
= render partial: 'universal_partial', collection: districts, as: :variable_name

= render partial: 'universal_partial', collection: subways, as: :variable_name


<li><a><%= variable_name %></a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But how can I get name of the variable inside partial? I.e. passed value of the `:as`

Comment: The name is what you pass in `as` parameter. Look at my example. I passed  `:as => :variable_name`, then I used in in the view `<%= variable_name %>`

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Moreover we found strange bug (in rails 3.1, not tested for early versions): inside partial is variable with same name as partial.This variable has `nil` value and overrides any helper with same name.